# How to disable all controls in Rad Grid on button click event?

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik-grid

I have a Rad Grid with batch editing enabled. Now I have to make my grid as Read Only which means I have to disable all the controls and the grid should not be editable. 
I have added a button **Preview** and when I click on that button I need to disable the all the controls.
How do I do this?

Comment: Hello, please take a time to go through the welcome tour to know your way around here , read how to create a [mcve] example and also check [ask] so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Answer (score 0):

In order to disable radgrid, you have to set the Enabled property of the control to false and switch off the auto postback on row click, column resizing, client row selection and keyboard navigation. Here is the documentation which shows how to enable/disable RadGrid.

[Enabled/Disabled conventions](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/grid/visible-and-enabled-conventions/enabled-disabled-conventions)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I will try this .

Comment: If that solved your problem can you please add the selected answer?

Comment: I added two functions to disable and enable the controls in the Rad grid , and called that function on a button click. This is how it worked for me.